# SQL - SUM and grouping

Tags: sql, sum, grouping

I have a following table:

| ITEM | Date | VALUE | START DATE | END DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 Jan 2023 | 15 | 01 Jan 2023 | 02 Jan 2023 |
| 1 | 02 Jan 2023 | 20 | 02 Jan 2023 | 03 Jan 2023 |
| 1 | 03 Jan 2023 | 25 | 03 Jan 2023 | 04 Jan 2023 |
| 1 | 04 Jan 2023 | 40 | 04 Jan 2023 | 05 Jan 2023 |
| 2 | 01 Jan 2023 | 30 | 01 Jan 2023 | 02 Jan 2023 |
| 2 | 02 Jan 2023 | 20 | 02 Jan 2023 | 03 Jan 2023 |
| 2 | 03 Jan 2023 | 10 | 03 Jan 2023 | 04 Jan 2023 |
| 2 | 04 Jan 2023 | 40 | 04 Jan 2023 | 05 Jan 2023 |

From here I need to have calculated sum of all values for every given row/date that are within dates in Start and End Date columns (boundaries included), so it is grouped by item and per date.

| ITEM | Date | VALUE_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 Jan 2023 | 35 |
| 1 | 02 Jan 2023 | 45 |
| 1 | 03 Jan 2023 | 65 |
| 1 | 04 Jan 2023 | 40 |
| 2 | 01 Jan 2023 | 50 |
| 2 | 02 Jan 2023 | 30 |
| 2 | 03 Jan 2023 | 50 |
| 2 | 04 Jan 2023 | 40 |

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What are **data types** of your `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` columns?

Comment: Why is the (1, 01 Jan 2023) sum 35?

Comment: I've tried several groupings by item, but can't find idea how to group it by date and keep sum that is calculated over the couple of dates.

Comment: @jarlh for that date/row I need to calculate sum within range of Start and End date (so it sums values from 01 Jan 2023 and 02 Jan 2023), but only for Item 1

Comment: @PM77-1 data type is 'date'

Comment: Alright, now I see.

Comment: OK. Now back to my 1st question: what stops you from completing the task on your own?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a *correlated subquery* to do the calculation:

```
select item, date,
       (select sum(value) from table t2
        where t2.item = t1.item
          and t2.date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date)
from table t1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! Right to the point!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only working with one month of data - one option could be to extract the day value from each date and then sum up each value while grouping by day.

This can be done by firstly creating a new variable in your dataset to store the day value:

`alter table dataset add day int;`

Values can then be extracted:

`update dataset set day=extract(day from date);`

Then, it is a matter of grouping the values by day:

`select day, sum(value) as value_sum from dataset group by day order by day;`